# Problems with this-parent and this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a little quiz in jquery. So I'll have several div-blocks with each 2 li-elements (one for yes, one for no). Clicking one of these li-elements updates a variable, gives visual feedback and toggles the display of either the current div and the next div. That's the plan.

I do use this js-code:

```
var ergebnis = 0;
$(this).click(function () {
    console.log(this.className);
    if ($(this).hasClass("ja")) {
        ergebnis++;
        $(".ergebnis").html(ergebnis);
        console.log(ergebnis);
    } else {
        ergebnis = ergebnis + 5;
        $(".ergebnis").html(ergebnis);
        console.log(ergebnis);    
    }
    //Styles updaten
    $("#frage__1 li").not(this).css({
        opacity: '0.2',
        transition: '1s'
    });
    $(this).css({
        background: 'green',
        transition: '1s'
    });
    $("#frage__1").slideToggle("slow", function () {});
    $("#frage__2").slideToggle("slow", function () {});
});
```

And this html-code:

```
<!-- Frageblock 1 -->
       <div id="frage__1" class="frage">
        <h2>1. So you ever wanted to get alongside?</h2>
        <ul>
            <li class="ja"><h3>Yes</h3><p>Extra Text</p></li>
            <li class="nein"><h3>Nope</h3><p>Extra Text 2</p></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

              <!-- Frageblock 2 -->
       <div id="frage__2" class="frage">
        <h2>2. So you ever wanted to get alongside?</h2>
        <ul>
            <li class="ja"><h3>Yes</h3><p>Again text</p></li>
            <li class="nein"><h3>Nope</h3><p>And another one</p></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

So you may already see that this is not really functional, as I always need to toggle all div-blocks in the very end of the code by hand; and currently do only get a result from the else-part. The console also logs me "undefined" at the very beginning and I always get my result always updated by 5, no matter what I click.

So I am looking for a solution how to exactly use this.parent() and something like not(this).parent at the very end of the code and what I did wrong at the very beginning with "this"

Thanks so much!

Comment: You need proper selector, for a start, e.g: $('li').click(function () {...

Comment: Did you realize that there's no class ".ergebnis"?? You're using a selector which no exists. So, undefined is normal.

Comment: I have a .ergebnis-block but didn't show it in this example here. Like this `<div><h3 class="ergebnis">Result</h3></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try with these two small changes. First change your selector on the click handler from the following:

```
$(this).click(function () {
```

to the one below which uses the `li` element selector:

```
 $("li").click(function () {
     $li =  $(this); //save a reference of the clicked li element
```

also above saves a reference to the clicked `li` element. With `$li` you can you to obtain the grandparent `div` reference in of the two following ways to change css:

```
 $li.parent().parent().css({
        background: 'green',
        transition: '1s'
 });
```

alternative:

```
 $li.closest("div").css({
        background: 'green',
        transition: '1s'
  });
```

More info about [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1) methods. I hope this helps a bit :-)

Comment: Oh wow. That already helped a lot. To the second block: To style the question'd have 2nd prio, as I could also edit this via the structure a bit. But the very last block:
`$("#frage__1").slideToggle("slow", function () {});    $("#frage__2").slideToggle("slow", function () {});`
is rather important to me. I now tried to use your hint like this for the first thing like that:
`$(("li").parent().parent()).css.delay(1800).slideToggle("slow", function () {});`
But it doesn't work out. Do I do something wrong with them brackets?

Comment: @Daiaiai, thanks if it was helpful :-)  About the slideToggle() - I'm not sure what way it needs to work. I tried one way. Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/hmjen298/1/ Let me know if it's okay or if you need something different.